# VueJS TypeScript using ChartJS - Parsing error: '}' expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, chart.js, eslint

I'm using Chart.js in Vue.

I npm installed chart.js & @types/chart.js .

I've added chart.d.ts containing `declare module 'chart.js';` .

Here's the error 
[image]

It says that it expects a closing curly bracket at line 43 however in my code, my IDE doesn't give any swiggly red lines at line 43 which generally indicates missing parentheses.

Here's the code:

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Chart from 'chart.js';

export default Vue.extend({
  name: "CompanyCardComponent",
  components: {
  },
  data() {
    return {
      color: "green" as string
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myChart');
    const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

    const myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'bar', <---------------------- Line 43 Line 43 Line 43 Line 43 Line 43
      data: {
          labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
          datasets: [{
              label: '# of Votes',
              data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
              backgroundColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 0.2)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 0.2)'
              ],
              borderColor: [
                  'rgba(255, 99, 132, 1)',
                  'rgba(54, 162, 235, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 206, 86, 1)',
                  'rgba(75, 192, 192, 1)',
                  'rgba(153, 102, 255, 1)',
                  'rgba(255, 159, 64, 1)'
              ],
              borderWidth: 1
          }]
        },
        options: {
            scales: {
                yAxes: [{
                    ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    })
  }
});
```

Here's my ESLINT Config (.eslintrc.js):

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  'extends': [
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    'eslint:recommended',
    '@vue/typescript/recommended'
  ],
  parserOptions: {
    ecmaVersion: 2020
  },
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off'
  },
  overrides: [
    {
      files: [
        '**/__tests__/*.{j,t}s?(x)',
        '**/tests/unit/**/*.spec.{j,t}s?(x)'
      ],A
      env: {
        jest: true
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

What's going on?

Comment: I don't see a syntax error here. By the way, `43:10` would indicate it's at 10 characters in the line which will put the error between `data` and `:`. Not sure what that means. Did you save the file? See if it's not cached or something?

Comment: I've saved the file & I've restarted VSCODE several times

Comment: I opened the webpage in question to the page in Chrome instead of Firefox (which I use) and it worked. It seems' you were right, it appears to have been a cache issue

Comment: Now I'm having the same issue in Chrome as well, I've cleared the cache but it is not being resolved...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the meanwhile, I've removed `lang="ts"` from my `<script>` tag in the .vue component file

Answer (score 1):

I think the issue is on the line :

```
const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById('myChart');
```

because of the case, you can use the as syntax to avoid the lint issue

```
const canvas = document.getElementById('myChart') as HTMLCanvasElement;
```

If you still have an issue check you .eslint.*, mine is like this:

```js
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true,
  },
  parser: 'vue-eslint-parser',
  parserOptions: {
    parser: '@typescript-eslint/parser',
  },
  plugins: ['vue','typescript'],
  extends: [
    'eslint:recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/eslint-recommended',
    'plugin:@typescript-eslint/recommended',
    'plugin:vue/essential',
    '@vue/typescript',
  ],
}
```

Answer (score -1):

eslintrc:

```
module.exports = {
  root: true,
  env: {
    node: true
  },
  extends: ['plugin:vue/essential', '@vue/prettier', '@vue/typescript'],
  rules: {
    'no-console': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'no-debugger': process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? 'error' : 'off',
    'prettier/prettier': [
      'warn',
      {
        printWidth: 140,
        jsxBracketSameLine: true,
        singleQuote: true,
        'no-multiple-empty-lines': ['error', { max: 2 }]
      }
    ]
  },
  parserOptions: {
    parser: 'typescript-eslint-parser'
  }
};
```

Answer (score -1):

tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "jquery"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*"
      ]
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```